How do i use nohup command for execute N processess in background on a server?
I'm using the command on a server for execute in background some processess:
nohup bash batch > logfile.txt 2>&1 <&- & 

but when i close my ssh session, the process batch is killed right before.
Another problem that i have with nohup is:
After execute batch in background, i want to start another batch process with different parameters, but everytime i start a batch with nohup as described above, the previous one get closed and the new one is started.
I've tried to use:
nohup source batch > logfile.txt 2>&1 <&- &

but everytime i close the ssh session i got the batch process closed.
I'm expecting to use N times the command below:
nohup source batch > logfile.txt 2>&1 <&- &

that runs N different instances of a program, configured by a conf file.

You may want to consider using screen as an alternative. It's been my go-to for remote server administration for years since it will stay running, as well as everything in it, through SSH sessions and whatnot.

@JNevill Thanks you for the rapid answer, what is screen ?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+nohup

Screen is a terminal multiplexer. Basically it means that you can start a screen session and then open any number of virtual terminals inside that session. These sessions live through SSH disconnects and whatnot.

tmux is a popular alternative to screen.

Similar/duplicate questions include How to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client in Linux, How to make a program continue to run after log out from ssh?, and Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine.

Also see the comment by Charles Duffy on Run Jobs Sequentially, in the Background, in Bash.

I could suggest an alternative nohupstrategy but using screen is the only proper way to run a background process from an SSH session is what I believe.

nohup doesn't put anything into background. "coproc" and "&" at the end of string does.
nohup is just preventing your background process to be killed with nohup signal and manages stdout/stderr to redirect them if they are not already redirected

TY all for the answers, it appears all clear to me now. Sorry for similar/duplicate questions
